# Using call/cc to make a loop. let vs begin

Tags: scheme, racket, continuations, callcc

Both of the following code blocks should (in my mind) be infinite loops

This works

```
(define call/cc call-with-current-continuation)

(define l 0)
(define i 0)

((lambda ()
   (call/cc
    (lambda (k)
      (set! l k)))
   (write i)
   (newline)
   (set! i (+ i 1))
   (l "ignore")))
```

This does not work:

```
(define call/cc call-with-current-continuation)

(define l 0)
(define i 0)

(begin
   (call/cc
    (lambda (k)
      (set! l k)))
   (write i)
   (newline)
   (set! i (+ i 1))
   (l "ignore"))
```

The only difference is one uses a lambda and one uses a begin block.
Why does the second block of code not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second case, the `begin` splices its arguments into the top-level. Note that there are [two kinds of `begin`](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/reference/begin.html): if it's in an expression position, it just sequences operations one after the other. The second kind (which is what you have) will splice all of its arguments into the surrounding context.

The spliced `call/cc` expression's continuation is actually the empty continuation, since each top-level expression is evaluated separately (i.e., in the empty continuation). You can check this by putting a `let` around the `begin`, which forces it to be in an expression position. Then it will infinite loop like you expect.

Comment: Thanks! Also, what is meant by "will splice all of its arguments into the surrounding context"?

Comment: (begin (begin 1) (begin 2 3) (begin 4)) will expand to (begin 1 2 3 4). The content of the inner begins are "spliced" into the context of the outer begin.